# I want to change remote git url to hairbodyskin-production in ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu

I want my repository to be hairbodyskin-production. But it is not changing.

[image]

I tried this

```
git config remote.origin.url https://x-token-auth:ATCTT3xFfGN02teIasCShaVu_OFcBiXmEGz5eXTLrjSOrRtyaZt-OU3r0II2rUS58_5auPxITl-L7aEVEge-aCHSUOZI4Cl0fgEtHSAzgX9Gg75Zrn2_pC1s7966yjgp4M1n0IshRyjKkleqGl2rxttxe6gbaHbCExkW0gbSDzc2Z4JgZlqlSoM\=65CB674A@bitbucket.org/cwdevelop/hairbodyskin-production.git
```

I also tried this

```
git config remote.origin.url --global https://x-token-auth:ATCTT3xFfGN02teIasCShaVu_OFcBiXmEGz5eXTLrjSOrRtyaZt-OU3r0II2rUS58_5auPxITl-L7aEVEge-aCHSUOZI4Cl0fgEtHSAzgX9Gg75Zrn2_pC1s7966yjgp4M1n0IshRyjKkleqGl2rxttxe6gbaHbCExkW0gbSDzc2Z4JgZlqlSoM\=65CB674A@bitbucket.org/cwdevelop/hairbodyskin-production.git
```

I also tried this

```
git remote set-url origin https://x-token-auth:ATCTT3xFfGN02teIasCShaVu_OFcBiXmEGz5eXTLrjSOrRtyaZt-OU3r0II2rUS58_5auPxITl-L7aEVEge-aCHSUOZI4Cl0fgEtHSAzgX9Gg75Zrn2_pC1s7966yjgp4M1n0IshRyjKkleqGl2rxttxe6gbaHbCExkW0gbSDzc2Z4JgZlqlSoM\=65CB674A@bitbucket.org/cwdevelop/hairbodyskin-production.git
```

Nothing worked for me.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Try this commands

```
git remote set-url --delete origin

git remote set-url origin <URL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a Magento question, and you should definitely remove all the private data from your question - tokens, URLs etc. - , and **change them** now that they have been public for 30 minutes, this may help:

`git remote remove origin`

`git remote add origin <my-new-url>`